# How can I rename NaN columns in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Good day everyone! I had trouble putting a nested dictionary as separate columns. However, I fixed it using the `concat`  and `json.normalize` function. But for some reason the code I used removed all the column names and returned NaN as values for the columns... 
Does someone knows how to fix this?

Code I used:

```
import pandas as pd

c = ['photo.photo_replace', 'photo.photo_remove', 'photo.photo_add', 'photo.photo_effect', 'photo.photo_brightness',
    'photo.background_color', 'photo.photo_resize', 'photo.photo_rotate', 'photo.photo_mirror', 'photo.photo_layer_rearrange',
    'photo.photo_move', 'text.text_remove', 'text.text_add', 'text.text_edit', 'text.font_select', 'text.text_color', 'text.text_style',
    'text.background_color', 'text.text_align', 'text.text_resize', 'text.text_rotate', 'text.text_move', 'text.text_layer_rearrange']
df_edit = pd.concat([json_normalize(x)[c] for x in df['editables']], ignore_index=True)
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('.').str[1]
```

Current problem: 
[image]

Result I want: 
[image]

Comment: Can you show a print of the `df.columns` before assigning the split columns names ?

Comment: @ManikTharaka "The result I want"  is a print of df.columns before executing the code I used.

Comment: Please share a proper [mcve], we need more context/background.

Answer (score 0):

```
df= pd.DataFrame({
    'A':[1,2,3],
    'B':[3,3,3]
})
print(df)
   A  B
0  1  3
1  2  3
2  3  3
c=['new_name1','new_name2']

df.columns=c

print(df)
   new_name1  new_name2
0          1          3
1          2          3
2          3          3
```

remember , lenght of column names (`c`) should be equal to column amount